# C Input won't add to array list

Tags: c, for-loop, integer, printf, conversion-specifier

The 2 arrays wont store input, the increment of each index number is always at 0 as printf states it.

```
int main()
{
  int ingredientsAmount;
  double ingredientsPrice[10];
  double ingredientsWeight[10];
  
  scanf("%d", &ingredientsAmount);
  
  for(int i = 0; i < ingredientsAmount; i++)  
  {
    scanf("%lf", &ingredientsPrice[i]);
    printf("Price stored at index %lf\n", i); 
    scanf("%lf", &ingredientsWeight[i]); 
    printf("Weight stored at index %lf\n", i); 
  }
  
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: OT: you might want to learn about structs.

Comment: I'm fairly new to programming itselfe so can u give me a link or explain me what structs is about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the incorrect conversion specifier `%lf` with an object of the type `int`. Use the conversion specifier `%d`. Write

```
printf("Price stored at index %d\n", i);
```

and

```
printf("Weight stored at index %d\n", i);
```

Or maybe you mean the following

```
printf("Price stored at index %d is %f\n", i, ingredientsPrice[i]);
```

and

```
printf("Weight stored at index %d is %f\n", i, ingredientsWeight[i]);
```

Pay attention to that the for loop is unsafe because the value of the variable `ingredientsAmount` entered by the user can be greater than the sizes of the declared arrays.

At least you should write

```
if ( scanf("%d", &ingredientsAmount) != 1 || ingredientsAmount > 10 )
{
   ingredientsAmount = 10;
}
```

Comment: I've learned from a source that using `scanf` is unsafe due to the reason that it can be used to overload a buffer. But i don't mind that rn cuz I just use what I've learned so far on EDX. And cant i use `scanf(10%d)` to get a cap of input? like 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 and more then 10 would be ignored?

Comment: @IYSZ No you can not do this way. In this case you need to use 10 conversion specifiers and corresponding arguments like (for 3 numbers) scanf( "%d %d %d", &x, &y, &z );

Comment: okey I will respond if it works for me. So far the `printf` is fixed :) so silly me haha

Comment: Btw, what do you mean with the last codeblock which is about the if statement to check if `ingredientsAmount` is not equal to 1 or bigger then 10? And why should then `ingredientsAmount` be = 10? wont it just override the input? Or is it just a "safeway" to override `ingredientsAmount` input if its greater then 10 like 11 100 12?

Comment: @IYSZ 1 is the return value of scanf that says that input was successful. The user can enter for example a letter instead of a digit or enter a value greater than 10.

Comment: Okey that was not my intention actually. "make sure that users cannot enter a number of ingredients greater than 10." < this is my goal and it works with `scanf(10%d)` as 10 is the max range the user can put in from 1 - 10